# Populating jQuery Autocomplete dropdown with promise data

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, promise, autocomplete

I'm getting a list of departments via a url and I'm able to see them in the console. What I want to do is display each of them in a dropdown that uses the plugin jQuery Autocomplete. The autocomplete needs a source (see code below) and it's supposed to put each array item in its own dropdown box, if that makes sense.

The thing is, I've inherited this code from someone else and they're using promises to help get the data, and I'm not sure how I'd get autocomplete's source to work with the promise data. I don't want to remove the promise functionality because it's working properly with other areas of this project.

#### JS snippet:

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl = siteAbsoluteUrl;
const deptList = "Departments";

async function makeGetRequest(url) {
  const response = await axios.get(url, getRequestConfig);
  const { results, __next } = response.data.d;
  return { results, __next };
}

// gives back an array containing all departments, without duplicates
export async function makeDepartmentsRequest() {
  const { results } = await makeGetRequest(
    `${baseUrl}/GC/getbytitle('${deptList}')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Department'`
  );

  return results[0].Choices.results;
}
    $('#combobox').autocomplete({
        source: makeGetRequest // ------ what should go here?
    }).on("click", function() {
        console.log("combobox clicked")
    });

makeDepartmentsRequest().then(res => console.log("res: ", res))
```

#### console.log:

"res:" ["BD/M...", "Bi...", "Engagement...", "Kno...", "Travel"]

#### html:

```
<input type="text" id="combobox" placeholder="Browse departments">
```

Comment: `what should go here` - depends, does `$.autocomplete` work with promises?

Comment: I looked at the documentation and it seems like it doesn't, but [this package](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/?id=_1-get-started) appears to work with it. I'll give it a shot

Comment: What documentation are you referring to @Tsardines?